# Programa de recursividad que devuelve cantidades mucho mayores

Tags: c++, recursión

El programa se supone que debe  calcular cuanto sera el valor de una  inversion despues de x años con una z tasa de interes. Por ejemplo con un monto
inicial de 5000, total de años 3 y la tasa de interés es 10 % entonces:
Año 0 tiene 5000
Año 1 tiene 5500
Año 2 tiene 6050
Año 3 tiene 6655

La función debe retornar 6655

sin embargo la mia me regresa  5000. Que estoy haciendo mal?

Aqui esta el codigo (n es monto, d es tasa de interes y a es año ) y mi caso base es que los años lleguen a cero, con cada llamada se le va restando al año:

```
int capital(int n,int d,int a)
{ 
    
    if ( a==0) 
    {
     
     return  n; 
    
    }
    else
    {
          return  n+(d/100)*capital(n,d,a-1) ;
    } 
}
```

Tal parece que no cambia para nada el monto de inversion, solo cambia el año que disminuye y luego aumenta (eso esta bien)

Comment: Cuando llamas a la función, ¿estás pasando el interés cómo 10 o cómo 0.1? Ten en cuenta que si lo estás pasando cómo 10 debes dividir `d` entre 100.

Comment: como 10, pero bueno aun asi cambiando da otra cosa que no

Comment: Y seguiste el codigo para ver que pasa?

Comment: Por cierto, sí o sí lo quieres resolver con recursividad, verdad? Porque hay una fórmula de interés compuesto para calcularlo directamente `C*(i+1)^n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeramente, tienes todo con `int`, por la naturaleza de las operaciones aritméticas de porcentaje que estás realizando deberías usar `float`, ya que el porcentaje puede bien NO ser exactamente un número entero.

Por otro lado, cambia la lógica del retorno. Debes en cada llamada incrementar `n` al nuevo monto con `interés`.

Tu función quedaría:

```
float capital (float n, int d, int a)
{
  if (a == 0)
    {
      return n;
    }
  else
    {
       float interes =  n * d / 100.0;
       float nuevoMonto = n + interes;
       return capital (nuevoMonto, d, a - 1);
    }
}
```

Puedes ejecutarla [online acá](https://onlinegdb.com/r24LPRGlP).

Comment: porque 1 +d? , si es para que  de la cantidad de monto con el porciento calculado mas la cantidad normal?

Comment: Para hallar el nuevo monto, se multiplica por ejemplo 1.1.  Por ejemplo si quieres sumar el a 200 su 10% simplemente multiplica por 1.1. Regla de 3. De cualquier forma te lo pongo más detallado.

Comment: Multiplicando por (1+d) te ahorras volverlo a sumar .

Comment: @nyanko ve a ver si así lo entiendes mejor.

Comment: ah okay si, gracias

Answer (score -2):

Si lo piensas al revés, las operaciones son:
6655 = 6050 + 605
6050 = 5500 + 550
5500 = 5000 + 500
5000 = 5000
Así que el resultado de f(n,d,a) = f(n,d,a-1) + f(n,d,a-1)*d
Ejemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
float capital(float n,float d,int a){
    if (!a) return  n;
    float anterior = capital(n,d,a-1);
    return anterior + anterior*d;
}
int main() {
    printf("Capital: %f",capital(5000,0.10,3));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Buena respuesta y muy bien explicada, pero ten en cuenta que la pregunta es de `c++`. La sintaxis que adjuntas no es directamente traducible a ese lenguaje. Considera escribir una versión en `c++`.

Comment: Aunque la respuesta y explicacion es correcta, la implementacion no... y la sintaxis muy diferente... considera traducirla.. o pedir que aporten tu explicacion a la respuesta con el codigo en el lenguaje correcto...

Comment: La duda que tiene esa persona es sobre recursividad. no sobre el uso del lenguaje en sí, he optado por JS para que sea directamente ejecutable en el sitio y no dependa de recursos externos. Además, creo que el código es perfectamente traducible.
De todas maneras acepto la modificación, gracias Daniel.